How to filter maps in QGIS to avoid manual export for each mast area
I'm working on a project in QGIS 3 that involves displaying different mast areas (e.g., mast areas 002-003) on individual maps.
My goal is to display the relevant biotopes for each mast area without having to export each mast area individually.
I want to use filtering to streamline the process and avoid repetitive data creation.
Requirements:
Each map should display the mast locations and the corresponding biotopes for the selected mast area.
I want to filter the biotope layer based on the mast area so that only the relevant biotopes are visible for each map.
Issue:
I attempted to apply a filter on the biotope layer using the following expression:
"Mastbereic" = '002-003'

I tried using a new rule (on top of the other rules) the biotopes display different colors, but I want to filter them for each area (for each atlas map) instead of creating endless data
I am only able to select or rename my filter, but not to only display my filter (if that makes sense).
